# What is the datatype for Cursor in Oracle Stored Procedure?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, cursor

I'm trying to run a Stored Procedure in Oracle. It's defined as the following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE real_estate_contracts
(
  P_FROM_DATE DATE,
  P_TO_DATE DATE,
  o_cursor  OUT ACCOUNTING_REPORTS.results_cursor 
 )
```

Then I'm calling it as such

```
BEGIN
  :P_FROM_DATE := to_date(trunc(trunc(sysdate,'MM')-1,'MM')+21);
  :P_TO_DATE := to_date(trunc(sysdate,'MM')+20);
  :O_CURSOR := NULL;


  QAW.REAL_ESTATE_CONTRACTS ( :P_FROM_DATE, :P_TO_DATE, :O_CURSOR );

END;
```

But I don't know how to defined the Cursor datatype.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want it defined as a SYS_REFCURSOR. Take a look at the following example: https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/using-ref-cursors-to-return-recordsets

Answer (score 0):

In SQL developer you can do:

```
VARIABLE cur REFCURSOR;

BEGIN
  QAW.REAL_ESTATE_CONTRACTS(
    p_from_date => ADD_MONTHS( TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'MM' ), - 1 ) + 21,
    p_to_date   => TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'MM' ) + 20,
    o_cursor    => :cur
  );
END;
/

PRINT cur;
```